Okta redirects to sign-in page post successful LinkedIn IDP sign-in
We are integrating the LinkedIn SignIn page with our SSO page. We are using a third-party authentication service provider Okta (https://www.okta.com/). We have created an App in the LinkedIn Developer portal recently. The app is mapped with IDP in Okta. We are facing a couple of issues with LinkedIn scopes with the Okta IDP APP. We have set openid, profile, and email in the LinedIn developer APP as scopes. On the Other hand, we set the same scopes in Okta IDP APP as well. During the login process, after the user signed In using LinkedIn credentials the LinkedIn response failed to map with the user in Okta. The LinkedIn email is already mapped with Okta uses. After validating the user using LinkedIn credentials it should be able to match with a user already created in Okta.
It seems we are facing issues with scopes ( openid, profile and email). We do have a few other apps created a few months ago with scopes r_emailaddress, r_liteprofile in both LinkedIn developer APP and IDP APP in Okta. The old apps are working as expected.
We would like to know if any way is there to set r_emailaddress, r_liteprofile as scopes. Or openid, profile, and email instead of r_emailaddress and r_liteprofil LinkedIn scopesonly supported?
I have tried to create new APP in Okta and new IDP in Okta. I have enabled all possible scopes on both Okta and LinkedIN side. I have tried various combination of scopes. None of them worked.
